# Should the intersection of 2 event sets be on the same sample space?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to understand a stochastic process and consecutive events in time.
Should the intersection of two events be on the same sample space, on a combination of *simultaneous* sample spaces, or a combination of *consecutive* sample spaces?

I have a question about $A\cap B$. Should the sets $A$ and $B$ be defined on the same sample space? If not, do these 2 events have to happen at the *same time*?

This question arises from this problem. Consider a discrete stochastic process with 
2 states,  $\{0,  1\}$ and 2 stages $t=1, 2$.  We can define 2 sample spaces:
for $t=1$, $\Omega_1=\{0,1\}$ and  for $t=2$, $\Omega_2=\{0,1\}$.

1. Can we define a *total sample space* $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$ even though the 2 events do **not** occur at the same time, but one after the other (consecutively)?
2. Assume that the probability of an event happening in $\Omega_1$ **affects** the probability of events in $\Omega_2$. In other word the **stationary transition** probability has been given, and also assume that the initial probability of states at $t=1$ has been given. Then what is the probability of event $[0,0]$ in $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$? 
   I would say, $\tfrac{\mathbb{P}[0 \mid t=2]}{\mathbb{P}[0 \mid t=1]}$.  
   My answer comes from this equation $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)*\mathbb{P}(B/A)$.
   But if $ P(A\cap B)$ should be defined on the same sample space,or 2 sample spaces both at the same time  and not consecutively, my answer is wrong.  
   The other answer can be  $\mathbb{P}[0  \mid t=1]* \mathbb{P}[0  \mid t=2]$ (by having $\mathbb{P}[0 \mid t=1]$ value and transition probability, we can calculate $\mathbb{P}[0 \mid t=2]$ and then multiply by $\mathbb{P}[0 \mid t=1]$).
3. Is there any difference between **transition** probability in a process (like Markov) and **conditional** probability that we define in set theory? I mean differences in the underlying sample spaces?